# I can't run any flutter commands after installing it. Nothing happens

Tags: flutter, installation

I installed flutter and set it to path, but when I tried to run any flutter command fx "flutter doctor" nothing happens.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/22MJq.png

What do I do from here?

I've uninstalled and reinstalled flutter, but it still does not work.

Comment: What happens when you run `flutter --version` ?

Comment: Nothing happens when I run `flutter --version`.

Comment: and what about `flutter -h -v`?

Comment: That does not work neither. Not even in in the flutter_console.bat.

Comment: did you follow standard installation procedure? like https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows? or some other way?

Comment: Yes I did, both the first and second time, where it did not work afterwards. But after your comment I did it again, and this time it worked for some weird reason. I can now run all the commands fx `flutter --version` and `flutter doctor`. Thanks for the help

Comment: this is because i have the special power of fixing bad flutter installations! remotely! ;-)

Comment: Well then thanks for working your woodo magic on my flutter installation. Really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

open windows terminal as an administrator....then run flutter it will install missing files if any then run flutter doctor to see if anything else is missing.....incase the command is not recognised please add the path to system variables

Comment: These operations are invalid if the command line does not recognize the 'flutter' command. There is a problem with the SDK installation.